# Notation confusion in likelihood question

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, bayesian, likelihood

Asking this question based on an equation I found in my homework:

"Given a training set, $\mathcal{S}$, find an expression for the likelihood, $p_\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{S}\mid w)=\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{S}\mid w]$ in the form: $A \exp(B)$. Characterise $A$ and $B$." $\mathcal{S}$ is drawn from a distribution $\mathcal{D}$.

Here, I can't understand what the question seems to ask, and what 'the likelihood, $p_\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{S}\mid w)=\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{S}\mid w]$' seems to suggest. What's the difference in use of fonts, e.g. $p$ against $\mathbb{P}$ and $()$ against $[]$ in probability theory.

I understand $p_\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{S}\mid w)$  indicates the probability of drawing the set $\mathcal{S}$ from a distribution $\mathcal{D}$ given a prior probability of $w$. However, the difference in fonts confuses me.

Futhermore, isn't that there already an equation? Am I supposed to solve for $p_\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{S}\mid w)$ or $\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{S}\mid w]$, going by the phrasing of the question?

Comment: This is non-standard notation and it is unclear to me what it means.  You should seek clarification from the lecturer that issued the homework.

Comment: The textbook should give the definitions somewhere earlier in the text, what does it say?

Comment: Please add `self-study` as a tag.

Comment: Noted about it being non-standard notation. There is no textbook, this was given in homework. I wasn't able to get anything from the lecturer. Thanks anyway everyone.

Comment: It may be that the lower-case $p$ represents a probability density function or a probability mass function. The usual use of the word "likelihood" in statistics might be consistent with $\mathcal D\mapsto p_{\mathcal D} (\mathcal S\mid w)$ being a likelihood function, but I would have been explicit about the input to the function being $\mathcal D. \qquad $

Comment: Update: After going through it some more, I do believe that lower-case $p$ does refer to the probability distribution function while the uppercase $\mathbb{P}$ refers to the probability itself. However, I only know that the error $e$ is drawn from a Gaussian distribution function with standard deviation $a$, and, and $y=wx+e$. I still can't figure out how I'm meant to find the likelihood, despite getting here.

Comment: Literally *every* real-valued function $f$ can be expressed in the form $A\exp(B),$ in infinitely many ways!  For instance, $f(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(Cf(x))\exp(\log(|f(x)|/C))$ works for any number $C\gt 0$ (understanding $0\exp(\log(0))=0$).